# Multiple audio and setting volume on Novocaine in iOS

Tags: ios, audio, core-audio, channel, novocaine

How do I play multiple audio and change its volume using Novocaine?

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is similar question which I wrote quite a lengthy response for

[Using Novocaine in an audio app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13291119/using-novocaine-in-an-audio-app/14047436#14047436)

Basically playing multiple sounds at once involves mixing the various sounds down sample by sample. Changing volume involves multiplying samples in the audio buffer by some amplitude value. That is if you want your output to be twice as loud simply multiply every sample by 2.0f. Accelerate framework can help you with this.